# Error in installing of pysam (error to build HSTlib) during of CNVkit installation

Tags: linux, installation, pysam

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWxoF.png)

I install the Linux server by VMware and try to install CNVkit but during the build of wheel in installation of pysam we have upper mentioned error. I had tried to install pysam separately but the same error was happened during of CNVVkit installation.